# Setting NSPredicate in Swift CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

Am Rewriting my existing objective c code(ios) to swift and now am facing some issues with Coredata NSPredicate in swift as there is some many to one relationships and vice-versa.. am using the following code,

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TUMessage")
    let sortSequence = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sequence", ascending: true)
    let sortTime = NSSortDescriptor(key: "epoch_time", ascending: true)
    var filterPredicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"thread == [c] %@",contact.threads.anyObject())
    fetchRequest.predicate = filterPredicate
    var sortDescriptor:NSArray = NSArray(objects: sortTime,sortSequence)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptor
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 50
    return fetchRequest
```

where    `"TUMessage"` is the table we need to fetch data from,  `"sequence"` for sorting the fetched result, `"thread == [c] %@"` is a relationship of message table (many to one since each contact have multiple thread) ,

and  `contact.threads.anyObject()` is the predicate which am trying to add.Unfortunately am getting the following error

```
  type anyobject? does not confirm to protocol, CVarArgType
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Thank you

Comment: I can't check it at the moment, but I assume that you have unwrap the optional: `contact.threads.anyObject()!`

Comment: If thread is a relationship, why are you performing a case insensitive search using [c]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unwrap it and cast to the specific class

```
contact.threads.anyObject()! as MYClass
```